# How to manipulate jQuery calendar

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I am short of idea of how I can achieve the following:

I need to customize jQuery calendar with the following criteria:

1. Depending on certain dates I retrieve from my database, I need to deselect or change the color of display of those dates on my calendar
2. Upon clicking on any date I need to be able to get the readings of the date from Monday to Friday of that date week.  e.g I click on 12 Feb, it must be able to supply the date from 7 to 13
3. If I click a range of dates, it must be able to give me the number of business work days, e.g If I select 8 Feb and 10 Feb, it must be able to give me 3 days.

Can I have a guide of how to do the above.  Thanks.

Comment: what is a jQuery Calendar? the jQuery UI datapicker? what component/extension are you basing your ideas?

Comment: I think I need to be clearer, I need the UI datePicker but I should be able to manipulate as per the requirements above.

Answer (score 0):

you need to find out first, what component would you use.

I would suggest [**FullCalendar**](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) as it's has built in all of those points, and [plenty more](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/).

> **FullCalendar** is a **jQuery plugin** that provides a full-sized, drag & drop calendar like the one below. **It uses AJAX to fetch events on-the-fly** for each month and **is easily configured** to use your own feed format (an extension is provided for Google Calendar). It is visually customizable and exposes hooks for **user-triggered events** (like clicking or dragging an event). **It is open source** and dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.

Comment: I don`t need such a powerful caledar, but rather do the above manipulation with the simple date picker

Comment: so use the jQuery UI DatePicker for that... how easy can that be?